# how to connect two nodes to one displacement output?

Tags: materials, node-editor

[image]

I need to connect the math node to  the displacement output but its currently being occupied by a height map. how can I connect both of these?

Comment: Connect them before the displacement. Each is a value indicating the displacement. Can use math or mix rgb, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a MixRGB node (more control) or a math node and select how you want to combine them.

Use clamp option if the values get to high (for example if you add them and you get higher values than 1).
[image]

Comment: I think scale from displacement is better than clamp